RPi Pico: infinite loop ISR with only one(?) interrupt
While running the script I experience a "infinite"loop of ISR's.
I try to achieve this:
The script is intended to keep the waterlevel in the container low.
Hardware:
I use a Pico, a relay and two sensors, one at a low position and one on a high position. Each sensor consists of two metal pins, “short-circuiting” (by the water) 3.3V from Pico to IN-pins on the board.
Software:
The control is done through a script on a Pico board. I use interrupts and flags to keep track of the process.
Proces:
When the script starts, the flags (flag_l and Flag_h) are set to zero.
When the water is rising, it first reaches the low sensor. Since I use a falling IRQ there, it will do nothing  with calm water (flag_l stays 0), but with some waves (e.g. heavy rain, level up&down) the sensor will now and then force the handler lf(18) to execute because the sensor is sometimes falling. The flag_l will then be set to 1 and stays so.
When the water level rises further and further, the high sensor comes into sight. The IRQ on that sensor forces the handler hr(21) to set the flag_h to 1 and the flag_l to zero. Flag_l = 0 AND flag_h = 1 activates the pump.
When the water is reaching the high sensor, the status of the flag_l is uncertain. However, in order to make it possible to de-activate the pump -when the water is on low level again- with flag_h (still) = 1 AND flag_l = 0), the flag_l has always to be set to 0 first thing after setting flag_h to 1.
The water level is falling, but that has no effect on the flag_h. The pump stays ON until the lower sensor is reached. When the IRQ on that sensor is falling, the pump is stopped and the flags are set to zero, ready for another cycle.
Code block:
from from machine import Pin, Timer
import time


# init pins
pomp = Pin(3, Pin.OUT)
l18 = Pin(18, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
h21 = Pin(21, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)


# definieer variabelen
flag_l = 0
flag_h = 0

# definieer callbacks
def hr(h21):
    global flag_h
    flag_h = 1
    global flag_l
    flag_l = 0
    print("H")
    
def lf(l18):
    global flag_l
    flag_l = 1
    print("L")

# definieer interrupts
l18.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=lf)
h21.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_RISING, handler=hr)

# Processing
while True:
    print(flag_l, flag_h, pomp.value())    
    print('in exec blok')
    if flag_h == 1:
        print("flagh")
        if (flag_h + flag_l) == 1:      
            pomp.value(1)
            print("PA")
            flag_l = 0
            time.sleep(2)
        elif (flag_h + flag_l) == 2:    
            pomp.value(0)
            print("PU")
            flag_l = 0
            flag_h = 0
            time.sleep(2)
    else:
        pomp.value(0)
        flag_l = 0
        flag_h = 0
        print("PU else")
        time.sleep(2)

I put some print statements in the script to see what is happening.
Later I tried to disable irq as first thing within ISR. Seemed to help a little, but not to much.
I do not understand why.
